# Pandas: Calculating value of difference between current column value and next column value depending if it meets criteria at a different column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [10, 'foo']), ('B', [440, 'foo']), ('C', [790, 'bar']), ('D', [800, 'bar']), ('E', [7000, 'foo'])], orient='index', columns=['position', 'foobar'])
```

Which looks like the below:

```
    position foobar
A   10       foo
B   440      foo
C   790      bar
D   800      bar
E   7000     foo
```

I would like to know the difference between each position and the next position that has the opposite value in the `foobar` column. Normally I would use the `shift` method to move down the `position` column:

```
df[comparisonCol].shift(-1) - df[comparisonCol]
```

but as I am using the `foobar` column to decide which position is applicable, I am not sure how to do this.

The result should look like:

```
    position foobar difference
A   10       foo      780
B   440      foo      350
C   790      bar      6210
D   800      bar      6200
E   7000     foo      NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need if unique values in `foobar` are only 2, so is possible shift between groups in `a` Series:

```
#identify consecutive groups
a = df['foobar'].ne(df['foobar'].shift()).cumsum()
print (a)
A    1
B    1
C    2
D    2
E    3
Name: foobar, dtype: int32

#get first value by a of position column
b = df.groupby(a)['position'].first()
print (b)
foobar
1      10
2     790
3    7000
Name: position, dtype: int64

#subtract mapped value, but for next group is added 1 to a Series
df['difference'] = a.add(1).map(b) - df['position']
print (df)
   position foobar  difference
A        10    foo       780.0
B       440    foo       350.0
C       790    bar      6210.0
D       800    bar      6200.0
E      7000    foo         NaN
```

Detail:

```
print (a.add(1).map(b))
A     790.0
B     790.0
C    7000.0
D    7000.0
E       NaN
Name: foobar, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is clever answer

Comment: Yes this really is very smart, and I wouldn't have thought about it in this way at all. Many thanks!