# Pandas: Calculating value of difference between current column value and the closest column value depending if it meets criteria at a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is an extension of this one: [Pandas: Calculating value of difference between current column value and next column value depending if it meets criteria at a different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671075/pandas-calculating-value-of-difference-between-current-column-value-and-next-co)

Initially I wanted to know the difference between each position and the next position that has the opposite value in the `foobar` column.

Here is a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [10, 'foo']), ('B', [440, 'foo']), ('C', [790, 'bar']), ('D', [800, 'bar']), ('E', [7000, 'foo']), ('F', [14000, 'bar']), ('G', [27000, 'bar'])], orient='index', columns=['position', 'foobar'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
    position foobar
A   10       foo
B   440      foo
C   790      bar
D   800      bar
E   7000     foo
F   14000    bar
G   27000    bar
```

Jezrael provided an excellent answer to finding the difference between each position and the next position that has the opposite value in the foobar column, producing the output:

```
    position foobar length
A   10       foo     780
B   440      foo     350
C   790      bar     6210
D   800      bar     6200
E   7000     foo     7000
F   14000    bar     NaN
G   27000    bar     NaN
```

However what I would now like to do is look both forward and backwards. So  `foo` and should look for the `bar` which is the nearest based on position, rather than just the nearest looking forward (down the column). So the output should actually look like:

```
    position foobar length
A   10       foo     780
B   440      foo     350
C   790      bar     350
D   800      bar     360
E   7000     foo     6200
F   14000    bar     7000
G   27000    bar     20000
```

As you can see several of the lengths are now changed as we are looking both up and down the foobar column. I confess to having no idea how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to apply the previous answer to the reverse-ordered dataframe and then combine the results.

```
# do solution from previous answer
print(df)

    position    foobar  difference
A   10          foo     780.0
B   440         foo     350.0
C   790         bar     6210.0
D   800         bar     6200.0
E   7000        foo     7000.0
F   14000       bar     NaN
G   27000       bar     NaN

# do the same thing on the reverse sorted df
df2 = df.sort_values(by=['position'], ascending=False)
a2 = df2['foobar'].ne(df2['foobar'].shift()).cumsum()
b2 = df2.groupby(a2)['position'].first()
df2['difference'] = a2.add(1).map(b2) - df2['position']
df2['difference'] *= -1
df2 = df2.sort_values(by='position')

print(df2)

   position foobar  difference
A        10    foo         NaN
B       440    foo         NaN
C       790    bar       350.0
D       800    bar       360.0
E      7000    foo      6200.0
F     14000    bar      7000.0
G     27000    bar     20000.0

# combine the two results
df['difference'] = pd.concat([df['difference'], df2['difference']], axis=1).min(1)

print(df)

   position foobar  difference
A        10    foo       780.0
B       440    foo       350.0
C       790    bar       350.0
D       800    bar       360.0
E      7000    foo      6200.0
F     14000    bar      7000.0
G     27000    bar     20000.0
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly and is really well explained too.